# Where to put Stripe Plan Creation in Sinatra Backend

Tags: ruby, sinatra, stripe-payments

I'm implementing my backend for my iOS app that uses Stripe for payments, using the [example provided](https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend), the only difference is my app uses only plans, not charges. I was just wondering where the [plan creation code](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/tutorial#create-plan) goes in [web.rb](https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend/blob/master/web.rb).

Is it like this:

```
post '/charge' do

  # Get the credit card details submitted by the form
  source = params[:source] || params[:stripe_token] || params[:stripeToken]
  customer = params[:customer]

  # Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
  begin
    Stripe::Plan.create(
      :amount => 2000,
      :interval => 'month',
      :name => 'Amazing Gold Plan',
      :currency => 'usd',
      :id => 'gold'
    )
  rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    status 402
    return "Error creating charge: #{e.message}"
  end

  status 200
  return "Charge successfully created"

end
```

Or should the plan be defined outside of the method? What I mean by this question is will this define a new plan called 'Amazing Gold Plan' every time `post /charge` is called, or will it just bind the new customer to the existing plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think what you're actually wanting to do is just create a Plan once, then create a Subscription.  A Subscription is a Plan that has been attached to a Customer.  Plans on their own don't actually do anything, but once they're used to create a Subscription, they can begin automatically charging your users.  Does that make sense?

You can create the Plan you'd like either through the Dashboard [1] or through the API [2].  When you're ready to use it, you can create a Subscription from inside the Dashboard when you're looking at a Customer Record or through the API [3].

In your case, what you would probably do is store the Plan ID (eg. `gold`) somewhere locally and create the Subscription using that Plan ID, rather than the Plan itself.

Hope that helps!

---

[1] https://dashboard.stripe.com/plans

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_plan

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription

Comment: yeah I kinda missed the part that says you can make the plan in the dashboard. Makes a lot more sense now.